# Eclipse was working fine this morning... Now it and the AVD crash every few minutes?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I was using Eclipse this morning and it was working fine, both it and the AVD would load in less than a minute... After a few hours it started crashing.

Now if I'm lucky enough for Eclipse to load without crashing the AVD takes at least half an hour to go from the basic "ANDROID" text to the actual logo.

I've tried cleaning my project, recreating the AVD, increasing the AVD's memory from 256mB to 1024, disabling animations and loading from snapshots...

Other than using Eclipse the only thing I have done with my computer is searching on stackoverflow.
What could have caused such a change in performance over a few hours?

Comment: I don't know the specific answer to your question, but I watch the same issue on a regular basis on my (Ubuntu 12.04 64bit) work machine: at startup everything runs well and fast, after hours of work (including mainly eclipse & firefox) everything slows down or completely refuses working. I assume it's a os problem (caching?). What helps is: **reboot**.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you started a background application or something. Restart your machine. Your memory is probably being barraged somewhere. Check that the processor isn't on battery save mode or anything.

Also, perhaps [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator?newsletter=1&nlcode=252%7C91bc) might help.